# Analyse who logged in using Syncope Logs

Tags: apache-syncope

I would like to keep track on which user logged into syncope console, when , and what are the changes done by the particular user; using logs. Is this possible and if Yes, which logs i have to look into ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the core.log

It's called main if you access it from within the dashboard.

You can also extend the built in audit